# How make multiple similar rows by a column into single row based on time

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have the Vehicles Entry & Exit Record but I need to make them into a single row with column exit_time & entry_time based on the timestamp.

I tried to use the JSON_ARRAYAGG() but didn't get the results my way.

**Table look like**

| id | vehicle_number | action | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XH5699TY | ENTRY | 22-08-01 10:08:47 |
| 2 | CV5632YR | ENTRY | 22-08-01 11:20:17 |
| 3 | CV5632YR | EXIT | 22-08-01 16:48:46 |
| 4 | XH5699TY | EXIT | 22-08-01 19:18:54 |

**What I need to do is make them into a single based on timestamp as entry-exit pair**

| id | vehicle_number | timestamp | entry_time | exit_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XH5699TY | 22-08-01 10:08:47 | 22-08-01 10:08:47 | 22-08-01 19:18:54 |
| 2 | CV5632YR | 22-08-01 11:20:17 | 22-08-01 11:20:17 | 22-08-01 16:48:46 |

Comment: Are you looking for an SQL Statement? Im confused because you tagged this question also with javascript.

Comment: @cdold Just added javascript tag for better reach. But yes I will take reference from here and then make a statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` on the same table, let's call it `vehicle_actions`. One tricky part is to identify the correct EXIT for multiple ENTRIES from the same vehicle.

The next query is identifying the entries and is looking for it, the minimum exit timestamp:

```
SELECT v1.id, v1.vehicle_number, v1.timestamp AS entry_time, MIN(v2.timestamp) AS exit_time 
FROM vehicle_actions AS v1
LEFT JOIN vehicle_actions AS v2 ON v1.vehicle_number = v2.vehicle_number AND v2.action = 'EXIT' AND v2.id > v1.id
WHERE v1.action = 'ENTRY'
GROUP BY v1.id, v1.vehicle_number, v1.timestamp
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I run a SQL query based on your table data. This May Help you a lots

```
select id,vehicle_number,timestamp, max(case when action = 'ENTRY' then timestamp 
end) as entry_time,
max(case when action = 'EXIT' then timestamp end) as exit_time
from table_name
group by vehicle_number
```

Note : kaka is table name

You can see The Real Result : [image: kaka is table name]

If You want to ORDER BY id just simply add

```
ORDER BY id
```

Else you want to ORDER BY timestamp just add

```
ORDER BY timestamp
```

after end of the operation.